# What SIGNAL is emitted in Qt when pressing the "X" on the top right corner to terminate the Window?

Tags: qt, qt5, signals-slots, qdialog, qapplication

Which SIGNAL is emitted, when pressing the "X" in the top right corner of a Qt Window application?

I have a second QDialog widget beside my MainWindow in my Qt application. And I would like to intercept the press on the "X" in my second QDialog, how?

Answer (score 0):

The `QCloseEvent` class contains parameters that describe a close event. Close events are sent to widgets that the user wants to close, usually by choosing "Close" from the window menu, or by clicking the X title bar button. They are also sent when you call `QWidget::close()` to close a widget programmatically.

To ignore it you can call `ignore()` method:

```
void YourDialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* iEvent)
{
  // ignore close event
  iEvent->ignore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no signal for that, you need to reimplement [QWidget::closeEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) or install an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) filtering for [QCloseEvents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcloseevent.html).